# Python JSON get data from response

Tags: python, json

after searching a lot I think I have just half of the answer to my problem
When I got a json response it is like this

```
{
    "queryResponse": {
        "@last": 3,
        "@first": 0,
        "@count": 4,
        "@type": "ClientDetails",
        "@requestUrl": "https://1.1.1.1/webacs/api/v2/data/ClientDetails?userName=contains(&quot;usertest&quot;)",
        "@responseType": "listEntityIds",
        "@rootUrl": "https://1.1.1.1/webacs/api/v2/data",
        "entityId": [
            {
                "@type": "ClientDetails",
                "@url": "https://1.1.1.1/webacs/api/v2/data/ClientDetails/236551459",
                "$": "236551459"
            },
            {
                "@type": "ClientDetails",
                "@url": "https://1.1.1.1/webacs/api/v2/data/ClientDetails/267361256",
                "$": "267361256"
            },
            {
                "@type": "ClientDetails",
                "@url": "https://10.141.1.29/webacs/api/v2/data/ClientDetails/370079361",
                "$": "370079361"
            },
            {
                "@type": "ClientDetails",
                "@url": "https://1.1.1.1/webacs/api/v2/data/ClientDetails/501402176",
                "$": "501402176"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Since I want to get a list of @url but I've just been able to get to entityId

```
json_obj = response.json()
object = json_obj['queryResponse']
entityId = object['entityId']
print(entityId)
```

And I cant print from entityId but I am not able to get just the field every @url field. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Basically you need to loop to entityId and get particular object to read and access index of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for entity in entityId: 
    print(entity["@url"])
```

Answer (score 2):

Since here key-value pairs are returned you should parse each one sequentially.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

json_obj = response.json()

entityId = json_obj['queryResponse']['entityId']

for _ in entityId:
    pprint( _['@url'])
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Don't use `_` as a loop variable if you are actually going to use the loop variable.

Comment: Thanks, COLDSPEED, I'm new to python though. Just being curious may I know why it is not recommended to use _?

Comment: `_` is to be used when you want to "throw away" the loop variable (i.e., if you don't plan to use it in the body of the loop).

Comment: Ohh okay, Thank you :).